# Thinger.IO response timestamp (1486047553711) string to Date time

Tags: javascript, c#, c

I am using thinger.io for my project.

I send request to fetch registered devices in thinger.IO and its details by using following URL

[http://{myip}/v1/users/username/devices?authorization={mytoken}](http://%7Bmyip%7D/v1/users/username/devices?authorization=%7Bmytoken%7D)

and i get the following response

```
[
 {
  "device":"nodemcu",
  "description":"NodeMCU With ESP8266",
  "connection":{
  "active":true,
  "ts":1486047553711
 }
}
]
```

I want to convert the ts "1486047553711" to proper date time by using Javascript or with anything possible.

As I am beginner in `thinger.io`. Its getting hard for me to understand their document.

Any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 1486047553711 is the date as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. You can convert it to javascript date by passing it in the constructor.

For example

```
new Date(1486047553711);
```

Comment: It is working well in javascript. any idea about C# ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to proper date format by passing it to date constructor:
 new Date(1486047553711);
the response is : Thu Feb 02 2017 20:29:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: It is working well in javascript. any idea about C# ?